# How Do I Modify an Attribute in XIB from C# Code

Tags: xcode, visual-studio-mac

I have the following code in a HelpWindow.xib file:

```
<string key="NSWindowTitle">HardCodedValue Help</string>
```

I want to provide a variable value rather than `HardCodedValue`.

**How do I accomplish this from `HelpWindowController.cs` or `HelpWindow.cs`, or am I looking in the wrong place?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to accomplish this in `HelpWindowController.cs` by adding the following code:

```cs
public override void WindowDidLoad()
{
    base.WindowDidLoad();
    Window.Title = "My New Title";
}
```